# Error in profile view after updating the profile picture

Tags: drupal-7

I updated the profile picture (after login in front end )using  edit profile , the image upload successfully.

but when i click to view the profile view, its show me error

```
"Fatal error: Cannot use 
object of type stdClass as array in /home/vhosts/Online-Education-Portal/Project/includes/common.inc on line 5808".
```

I dont know what might be the issue, i checked with the common.inc but no response.

Answer (score 1):

After struggle 2 days finally i got answer for my question.
    i just write the one condition in common.inc,

```
if(is_object($elements)) //check the array elements is object
{
 $elements=(array)$elements  //change to array from object
 return $elements;
}

the above line is solved my problem.
```